# RxJS testing catch operator using Jasmine Marbles always fails

Tags: jasmine, rxjs, jasmine-marbles

I'd like to test that if an observable catches a thrown error from inside one of its operators, I get the expected resulting observable.

The service below returns an observable that throws an error or not depending on its error param.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

export function service(obs1: Observable<number>, obs2: Observable<number>, error: boolean = false) {
  return obs1.merge(obs2)
    .map((elt) => elt * 2)
    .do(() => {
      if (error) {
        throw new Error();
      }
    })
    .catch(() => Observable.of(0));
}
```

With this Jasmine Test

```
import { cold } from 'jasmine-marbles';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { service } from './catch';

describe('Test Marbles', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    const e1 = cold('-a-|', {a: 1});
    const e2 = cold('--b-|', {b: 2});
    const expected = cold('-ab-|', {a: 2, b: 4});
    const obs: Observable<number> = service(e1, e2);
    expect(obs).toBeObservable(expected);
  });

  it('should handle error', () => {
    const e1 = cold('-a-|', {a: 1});
    const e2 = cold('--b-|', {b: 2});
    const expected = cold('-c', {c: 0});
    const obs: Observable<number> = service(e1, e2, true);
    expect(obs).toBeObservable(expected);
  });
});
```

I get the output below for the second test that fails.

```
Expected [ Object({ frame: 10, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: 0, error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }), Object({ frame: 10, notification: Notification({ kind: 'C', value: undefined, error: undefined, hasValue: false }) }) ] to equal [ Object({ frame: 10, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: 0, error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }) ].
```

Answer (score 5):

When you `catch` observable's error, it is emit returned value from catch's result selector and *completes* observable as normal, since it doesn't emit `error`. So expected marble output is `-(c|)`, where value is emitted and observable completes immediately.

Comment: Thanks  Could you please elaborate the difference between (c|) and c|. Does the second mean that termination would be done on the next frame ?

Comment: yes, each char represents single frame, while () means it's grouped happens in single frame.